# Disappointing iOS search times with CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, full-text-search, uisearchbar, nsfetchrequest

I have a coredata db running on an ipad with iOS 5.1.1.  My database has around 50,000 companies in it.  I have created an index on the company name attribute.  I am searching on this attribute and on occasion get several thousand records returned with a fetchRequest.

When several thousand records are returned then it can take a couple of seconds to return from the fetch.  This makes type-ahead searching pretty clunky.

I anticipate having much larger databases in the future.  What are my options for implementing a really fast search function?

Thanks.

Comment: yep, the real time searching is not the best idea in case of 50K+ objects.

Comment: Also do you really need to search that many items as a type-ahead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend watching the core-data performance videos from the last few WWDCs.  They often talk about strategies for improving this kind of bottleneck.  Some suggestions from the videos :

- De-normalise the name field into a separate "case and diacritic insensitive" `searchString` field and search on that field instead, using `<`, `<=` or `BEGINSWITH`.  Avoid `MATCHES` and wildcards.
- Limit the number of results returned by the `NSFetchRequest` using `fetchLimit` and `fetchBatchSize`
- If your company object is large you can extract some of the key data items off onto a separate smaller "header" object that is used just for the search interface. Then add a relationship back to the main object when the user makes a selection.

Some pointers to a couple of videos (there are more from other years also):

WWDC 2012: Session 214 - Core Data Best Practices : 45:00

WWDC 2010: Session 137 - Optimizing Core Data Performance on iPhone OS: 34:00

Answer (score 1):

While Core Data is the correct tool in many cases, it's not a silver bullet by any means.

Check out this post which discusses a few optimizing strategies and also cases when an SQL database is your better choice instead of Core Data:

http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data

You may honestly be better off using an SQL database instead of Core Data in this case because when you try to access attribute values on Core Data entities, it typically results in a fault and pulls the object into active memory... this can definitely have performance and speed costs. Using a true database - Core Data is not a true database, see http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html - you can query the database without creating objects from it.